# "I could eat a horse" - Why 'could'?

Tags: idioms, conditional-constructions

"I could eat a horse" is a [well-known](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+could+eat+a+horse) phrase.

I wonder why the modal-verb 'could' is used.

According to this source ([EnglishPage](https://www.englishpage.com/modals/could.html)),

> "Could" is a modal verb used to express possibility or past ability as
>   well as to make suggestions and requests. "Could" is also commonly
>   used in conditional sentences as the conditional form of "can.

It looks like the statement ("I could eat a horse") doesn't express any of the options above. I tend to view this statement as **a present ability**, so perhaps 'can' is a better option?

Comment: That's a truncated version of the more complete expression ***I'm so hungry,*** *I could eat a horse.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's a hypothetical, or counter-factual possibility, so we use "could". The implication is "If there were a horse here, I could eat it". It's effectively conditional.

Comment: "...But in fact that is no horse here so I'm not eating a horse", counter factual.